# Powermail (7.4.0) default Captcha keeps failing with TYPO3 9.5.7

Tags: typo3, captcha, extbase, typo3-9.x, powermail

I am trying to configure captcha field with powermail. It always throwing error `Captcha: Falscher Captcha Code eingetragen, bitte erneut versuchen!`, I tried to investigate the causes of the issue. I found if I remove below rewrite rule from `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]
```

...then it's working correctly and form submission will succeed. But, this will lead you to another problem. As rewrite rule above redirect you to index.php if the file/symlink/directory does not exist, So this won't work. Now, your home page will work fine but inner pages will lead you to 404 error.

See:

[image]

Here is my apache configuration for virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.relaunch.typo-site.de
    ServerAlias relaunch.typo-site.de

    <Directory  "/var/www/html/relaunch">
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help me with this? I found a similar open issue at the [Github repository](https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/issues/466).

Comment: Have you tried a current version of TYPO3 yet? The current release is 9.5.19 - you're 12 versions behind the latest release.
Just tested powermail 7.4.0 in TYPO3 v9.5.19. Captcha worked with confirmation page and without confirmation page. .htaccess was the one shipped as example with TYPO3 core.

Comment: Hi @JulianHofmann, I have lil old version. But, it working correctly in my local server. Issue raised at my live server only :(